# Use Case Diagram Show Submit or Empty Form

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

When creating a use case diagram, I want to show that a user can submit a form or empty all fields (or cancel the action)
Since both submitting the form (let's call it add user) and empty fields are related, how can I show this in a use-case diagram?
I was thinking of extending add user with empty fields, but as the extended use-case depends on the base use-case, is it correct to show something like this?

[image: Use Case: Add User or Empty Fields]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make atomic actions use cases. The use case has to provide some business value.

What you're describing is a flow of a use case. Use case diagram documents list of use cases and relationship between them (and to actors), but not flows of the use cases.

To show show the action flow inside a UC you should create activity diagram. It'll show a possibility of clearing or submitting the form.

Comment: If the order of use cases is important, this can be shown with `<<precondition>>` constraints. Rather than _show use case flow_ it should be _show the action flow inside a UC_.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKilian, I've corrected the text as you have suggested.